# Changing map language - is it possible?

Tags: cloudmade

Is it possible to get cloudmade map tiles in English for area which are not in English by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now it's not possible, but we will add multilangual support for CloudMade map styles in future.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can customise some aspects of CloudMade's map tile rendering using their "style editor" tool, language options are not (yet) available

For efforts to achieve this within the wider OpenStreetMap community (rendering using the names data which *is* in the OpenStreetMap database for many place names) **see the information on [Map internationalization](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_internationalization).**

You can point to tile sources other than CloudMade's using the leaflet library, but note that serving map tiles is a little resource intensive so pointing your leaflet library at someone else's tile server for a high traffic website may not be welcome (terms of use & service guarantees vary)